# Web Component Tester- Not finding chrome locally

Tags: testing, polymer, polymer-1.0

Title saids it all:

```
one@localhost ~/github/my-el $ polymer test -l chrome
step: loadPlugins
step: configure
hook: configure



Error: The following browsers were not found: chrome. (All installed browsers found: )
```

---

```
one@localhost ~/github/my-el $ which chrome
/usr/bin/chrome
one@localhost ~/github/my-el $ lr /usr/bin/chrome
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jul  8 21:25 /usr/bin/chrome -> /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

---

Reference https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities and

https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/blob/master/runner/config.ts#L127

```
one@localhost ~/github/my-el $ cat wct.conf.json
{
  "verbose": true,
  "plugins": {
    "local": {
      "browsers": ["chrome"],
      "browserOptions": {
        "browserName": "/usr/bin/chrome",
        "platform": "LINUX"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/issues/222

place this in the shell for good times `export LAUNCHPAD_CHROME=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`

I was going to delete this post but I will leave it up for easy reference for other good souls searching for answer.

Comment: It helped me to run my tests locally. Thanks.
But, I noticed that you are using `browserOptions` as a property of `plugins.local` in your wct.conf.json.

Shouldnt be `browsersOptions` instead? I've found this on the documentation [1] of the wct-headless.

[1]: https://github.com/t2ym/wct-headless

Comment: hahaha, you're right, it was some time ago. thats fine, dude. thanks :)